# Release tag is sometimes absent in the workflow

Tags: github-actions

I've a workflow which creates an image and pushes it to a docker repository. The image is tagged with the latest version name. This works fine for the most part, but sometimes the tag - taken from `github.ref_name` - is empty.
When its empty, the workflow description looks different, too:

[image]

As you can see, the upper workflow failed. It has the title from the workflow name and doesn't seem to know a release tag. The lower one displays the title from the release (which is just `"v0.0.26"`), and displays the release tag in its description. Re-releasing helps, though.

Here's a shortened version of the workflow file:

```yaml
name: Publish dockerimage for release
on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  generate:
    name: Create release docker image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build the docker image
        id: build
        run: |
          docker build . --file build/builder/Dockerfile --tag new-image
      - name: Push development docker image to registry with tag
        run: |
          docker tag new-image ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST}/${DOCKER_REPOSITORY}:${DOCKER_TAG}
          echo ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} | docker login ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST} --username=${DOCKER_USERNAME} --password-stdin
          docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST}/${DOCKER_REPOSITORY}:${DOCKER_TAG}
        env:
          DOCKER_TAG: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST }}
          DOCKER_REPOSITORY: wecreate/${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
```

If the error occurs, it reads like `Error parsing reference: "***/myCompany/myRepo:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format` - so the tag is missing. Does anybody have an idea about this indeterministic behavior?

Comment: Does it work as expected using `github.event.release.tag_name` instead of `${{ github.ref_name }}`?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for your suggestion! Hard to tell, though, since it fails only occasionally. But I can give it a shot and observe over the next days/month. ;)

Comment: After some researches it seems to be something that started happening recently ([Reference](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/64528)). And using the `github.event.release.tag_name` context variable instead should always work for the release event.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Well, "`github.ref_name` context variable is only available when the workflow is triggered by a push event to a branch or tag" doesn't match with my experience, but still it might be worth to drop `ref_name` if it's not only becoming unreliable for unknown reasons, but also by design. :) Thank you so far. Dunno, if there's no explanation, I'ld accept your advice as an answer ... it's at least a workaround which (hopefully) works.

Comment: I agree it wasn't working like that before (I've got some workflows using the `github.ref_name` as well for published release). However, it does seem more reliable to use `github.event.release.tag_name` instead, as this variable is specific for the release event context.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Well, I had 24 generated services yesterday (with the same workflow file). I merged and released all of them with a script. 21 of them succeeded, including the last ones. So it's more than just a general change in behavior.

Comment: You're right, it might also be an unexpected behavior due to an instability on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some researches, it seems indeed that the `github.ref_name` context variable started coming empty for `release` events recently, as other are experiencing the same issue (cf. [Github Community](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/64528)).

*Note: It's hard to tell now if it's an unexpected behavior due to an instability on GitHub, or a general change in behavior.*

As your workflow is only triggered for **published release** events, it seems more reliable to use the `github.event.release.tag_name` context variable instead, as it will always be filled for `release` events.

Therefore, I would suggest substituting `${{ github.ref_name }}` by `${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}` in your workflow.